# Customize amCharts date aggregation level

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I would like to customize the date aggregate(axis labels) for amCharts, but I couldn't find a provision to do this in amCharts docs. Googling the same just pointed me to the `dateFormats` documentation.

amCharts provides an option for aggregating date by setting `parseDates` to `true` and adding `dateFormats` as shown below. This option aggregates date by doing some calculation by amCharts itself, let's say 25 days for week aggregation(Jan 5), 65 days for month aggregation(Jan) and so on, but I would like to customize the default date aggregation level.

```
parseDates: true,
dateFormats: [{
                fff: 'period',
                format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
            }, {
                period: 'ss',
                format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
            }, {
                period: 'mm',
                format: 'JJ:NN'
            }, {
                period: 'hh',
                format: 'JJ:NN'
            }, {
                period: 'DD', // day level
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
            }, {
                period: 'WW', // week level
                format: 'MM/W/YYYY'
            }, {
                period: 'MM', // month level
                format: 'MMM YYYY'
            }, {
                period: 'YYYY',
                format: 'YYYY'
            }]
```

I would like to change the default day, week, month levels in the following manner.

```
DAY LEVEL: <= 14 days
WEEK LEVEL: 14 < x <= 91
MONTH LEVEL: 91 < x <= 731
```

I would like to customize the date aggregation levels in amCharts. How could I do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with what you have done so far?

Comment: Did you meant label frequency by 'aggregation level'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set this so precisely. The next period is chosen when there are too many items in the selected period. You can try adjusting minHorizontalGap value of CategoryAxis: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minHorizontalGap (default is 75). If you make it smaller, more items will fit and you'll have more labels.

Comment: Hey man,can you check my last question, its regarding amcharts.